# Populating an array in do loop, allocating memory or not

Tags: list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I am doing a calculation where I have a do loop can be as long as 1 million. In each loop, I want to store a value into an array to plot afterward. In MATLAB normally I was preallocating the memory for the array like  `a=zeros(1000000,1);`   I have been told that in Mathematica I don't need to do that I can simply do `a={}` and in every loop  `a[[i]]=number`. Is this true? Or I should be doing something like `a=ConstantArray{0,1000000};`?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The approach `a={}` and then setting `a[[i]]=number` is *not* possible. One *could* use `Append` but it should be avoided for the same reasons as such methods should be avoided in Matlab.

If you cannot use `Table` to construct the array, preallocation with `a = ConstantArray[0,{1000000}];` is one way to go. If your array is supposed to contain machine floats then use `a = ConstantArray[0.,{1000000}];` and make sure that all values written into the array are also machine floats (otherwise, the array will be [unpacked](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496)). For complex machine  floats use `ConstantArray[0. + O. I,{1000000}]`.

In general, this approach will be rather slow as Mathematica is not very well at (uncompiled) loops of any kind. Often it is also advantage for performance to put the code into `Compile` -- provided that the code for generating the values is compilable.

## Examples

Here are three possible approaches for the additive assembly of a dense vector: One with `Do` (producing `a`); one with `SparseArray` (producing `b`, notice that one has to go through some pain to make it assemble additively); and one using a compiled helper function (producing `c`).

```
n = 1000000;
pos = RandomInteger[{1, n}, 10 n];
vals = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10 n];

(
   a = ConstantArray[0., {n}];
   Do[a[[pos[[i]]]] += vals[[i]], {i, 1, Length[pos]}];
   ) // AbsoluteTiming // First

b = With[{spopt = SystemOptions["SparseArrayOptions"]},
     Internal`WithLocalSettings[
      SetSystemOptions[
       "SparseArrayOptions" -> {"TreatRepeatedEntries" -> Total}],
      
      SparseArray[Partition[pos, 1] -> vals, {n}],
      
      SetSystemOptions[spopt]]
     ]; // AbsoluteTiming // First


(* compiled helper function; can be reused. Make sure that n greater or equal to Max[pos]. *)

cAssembleVector = Compile[{{pos, _Integer, 1}, {vals, _Real, 1}, {n, _Integer}},
   Block[{a},
    (* We use Table because ConstantArray is not compilable. *)
    a = Table[0., {n}];
    Do[
     (* Compile`GetElement is a read-only substitute of Part that skips bound checks and thus is faster that Part. Use with caution. *)
     a[[Compile`GetElement[pos, i]]] += Compile`GetElement[vals, i], 
     {i, 1, Length[pos]}
     ];
    a
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];

c = cAssembleVector[pos, vals, n]; // AbsoluteTiming // First

a == b == c
```

> 23.4489
>
> 1.59865
>
> 0.073619
>
> True

You see, `Do` performs really bad. Best is to use a compiled approach: it 300 times faster than `Do`. It might seem a bit tedious, but using `Compile` is still *much* easier than using mex-functions in Matlab.

Notice that this vector asembly features random read and write access and is somewhat a rather hard problem. There might be faster methods for generating more structured arrays.

## Final remark

If you don't know the length of the array in advance, [`` Internal`Bag ``](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6795762) might also serve as efficient substitute for `Sow` and `Reap`, in particular in compiled code. It is undocumented, though.

Answer (score 5):

If you know the number of elements in advance, use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html).

If you don't, use [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reap.html).

Given that you talk about preallocation and `Do` loops, it seems to me that you do know the number of elements, thus go with `Table`, or possibly with `Array`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to avoid preallocation of vectors and matrices for defining elements through desired loops. Here are two examples for such situation:

1- Defining Vectors' Elements:

```
Clear[a,i,j,b];
For[i=1,i<=10,i++,
a[i]=i^2;
];
b=Table[a[j],{j,i-1}]
b[[5]]
```

2- Defining Matrices' Elements:

```
Clear[i,j,a,b,n,m];
For[i=1,i<=3,i++,
For[j=1,j<=2,j++,
a[i,j]=i*j;
]];
b=Table[a[n,m],{n,i-1},{m,j-1}]
b[[3,2]]
b//MatrixForm
b[[3,2]]
```